# document.body.style is what a strange object

Tags: javascript, css

document.body.style(or element.style) is a instance of CSSStyleDeclaration , I wanna use this property to check out whether the browser support some specify css property

Like this

```
if("border-width" in document.body.style){
    //do sth. if supported
}
```

But:

I found a strange thing

```
document.body.style["border-width"] //""
document.body.style.hasOwnProperty("border-width") //true
"border-width" in document.body.style //true

//iterating from Object
for( var i in document.body.style){
    if( i == "border-width" ){
        console.log("found it")
    }
}
```

**but couldn't log "found it" last time**, it means we didn't find "border-width" in iteration.

Why?

Even **document.body.style[1111]** return "" but not undefined , are 1111 is a property too?

It's so strange and confused.

Comment: It means that it probably is a non-enumerable property.

Comment: Try `typeof document.body.style['whaveter']`. Non-assignable properties will return `"undefined"`

Comment: Btw, my `document.body.style` does not have a `["border-width"]`, only a `.borderWidth`. To use CSS names, you should go by `setProperty()`

Comment: it's not weird that they return empty string, it's just their implementation

Comment: if you see FF `document.body.style[111]` returns undefined... but `document.body.style['border-width']` will return the value for `border-width`, ie same value as `borderWidth`

Comment: I'm testing in Chrome Console ,  maybe it's a bug in chrome , I have tested in Firefox, it correctly perform ,  `document.body.style[111]` will return `undefined` and the iteration will get the property correctly , @ArunPJohny u are right

Comment: So why the random combination like 111,123,333.... could be the non-enumerable property? @Bergi

Comment: @zhiyishou: Those are not exactly "random" combinations - they are numbers. And as such they are handled in a Proxy-like manner by the `.item()` method, which returns the n-th property name: `CSSStyleDeclarations` are array-like, you can iterate them until their `.length` to get all the styles placed in it. Try to give your body an inline style and try `document.body.style.length` and `document.body.style[0]` or `document.body.style.item(0)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test whether or not a property is available, use `typeof`. For example

```js
var out = document.getElementById('out');

['background', 'backgroundColor', 'background-color', 'backgroundColour',
'-moz-border-radius', '-webkit-border-radius'].forEach(function(prop) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = '<code>' + prop + '</code> is ' + (typeof out.style[prop] === 'undefined' ? '<strong>not</strong> ' : '') + 'available';
  out.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<ul id="out"></ul>
```

Comment: I threw the `-webkit` one in there because it works in Chrome however Firefox doesn't seem to like any `-moz` prefixed properties even if they are supported in CSS

Comment: Your answer is right, but I think you haven't get my point, my point is why `document.body.style["border-width"]` could get the property but I couldn't find it in for iteration and `document.body.style[123]` does not return `undefined` in Chrome, but these all work correctly in FF, so I think maybe this is a small bug in Chrome

Comment: @zhiyishou Looks like you can access each property via a numerical index as well. For example, if I set `style="border-width: 0"`, `style[0]` returns `"border-top-width"`, `style[1]` `"border-right-width"`, etc

Comment: I think I understand what you say ,  but why `document.body.style[100000]` does not return `undefined` but `""` in Chrome, it return `undefined` in FF correctly. @Phil